# can not write log in separate file using Log4J and spring boot application in tomcat server

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2

I am new to the spring-boot applications and want to manage log properties to write logs to a separate file. But my logs print only in 'Catalina.out' file.

Here is some part of pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
    .
    .
    .
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    .
    .
    .
```

here is the log4j2-spring.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="60">
<Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">${catalina.base}/logs</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console-Appender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>
                [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
            </pattern>>
        </PatternLayout>
    </Console>
    <File name="App-File-Appender" fileName="${log-path}/app_log.log" >
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>
                [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </File>
    <File name="SpringBoot-File-Appender" fileName="${log-path}/springboot_log.log" >
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>
                [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </File>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.springframework.web" level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="SpringBoot-File-Appender"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="guru.springframework.blog.controllers" level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="App-File-Appender"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender"/>
     </Logger>
    <Root>
        <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

My spring-boot class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
 public class MyApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);

}
```

I wonder why my log file doesn't create logs didn't write in '>${catalina.base}/logs/logfile.

I also test putting this line in 'application.properties' :

```
logging.file=../logs/mylog.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write your application root package name i.e. the package contains all subpackages and classes of your application in `Logger` element `name` attribute -

In below lines -

```
<Logger name="guru.springframework.blog.controllers" level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="App-File-Appender"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender"/>
     </Logger>
```

Replace `guru.springframework.blog.controllers` with your application root package name.

Alternatively, you can add `App-File-Appender` in `Root Logger` -

```
<Root>
    <AppenderRef ref="App-File-Appender"/>
    <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender"/>
</Root>
```

But, the general convention of using `RootLogger` is to log error messages of the application dependencies.